# Error 91 in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub lstLookup_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'declare the variables
    Dim cPayroll As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim findvalue
    'error block
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'get the select value from the listbox
    For I = 0 To lstLookup.ListCount - 1
        If lstLookup.Selected(I) = True Then
            cPayroll = lstLookup.List(I, 1)
        End If
    Next I
    'find the payroll number
    Set findvalue = Sheet2.Range("F:F").Find(What:=cPayroll, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -3)
    'add the database values to the userform
    cNum = 21
    For X = 1 To cNum
        Me.Controls("Reg" & X).Value = findvalue
        Set findvalue = findvalue.Offset(0, 1)
    Next
    'disable adding
    Me.cmdAdd.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler::
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & "The error number is:  " _
           & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
           "Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48463127/edit) to format your code for easier reading and to include more information.

Comment: Please include the description of the error, and what line the error happens on in your question.

Comment: Error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 2):

In your question, make sure that you always mention where is the error. E.g., you are getting it on this line:

```
Set findvalue = Sheet2.Range("F:F").Find(What:=cPayroll, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -3)
```

This is because you are abusing the `Offset()` function with `.Find()`. E.g., try to see what could be found, before using the `Offset()`:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim findValue
    If Not Worksheets(2).Range("F:F").Find(What:=78, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Set findValue = Worksheets(2).Range("F:F").Find(What:=78, _
                                                        LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```